# Does jackson JSON parsing depends on the object's internal methods

Tags: json, jackson

I am trying to use jackson in a project and came across an observation. I found that that on changing the return type of the internal methods of the object being converted to JSON, the behavior of the jackson parser changes.

Does conversion of java object to JSON using jackson depends on the methods in the objects as well?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Jackson tries to do it's best to de/serialize java objects for you, and by default is configured to use maximum auto-detection.  See the 5 AUTO_DETECT* properties [here](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/MapperFeature.html#AUTO_DETECT_CREATORS) for more information.

If you do not want Jackson to be so sensitive to changes to your objects, you can disable these features on your `ObjectMapper` like this:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.disable(MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_CREATORS);
```